# How to refresh page after a throw exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, page-refresh

I have code that checks for certain values after the save button is clicked. The user enters a value into the textbox and if a value isn't selected from the dropdownlist then an exception will be thrown. The textbox has a default value of one. So if no reason is selected then display message. The problem is whatever value was put into the textbox is still there but if I manually refresh the page then it gets defaulted back to one. I need to refresh the page after the exception so the textbox goes back to the default value.

```
JobPieceSerialNo SerNo = new JobPieceSerialNo(job.ID);
if (SerNo.Reason == null)
{
     throw new Exception("Must select reason");
     Response.Redirect("Job.aspx?JobID=" + Request.QueryString["JobID"], false);
}
```

Putting the response code after the exception makes the code unreachable and putting it outside of the if statement doesn't seem to work either. So how can I refresh the page?

Comment: perhaps you should not be throwing an exception, but presenting a validation error message to the user?

Comment: @Kritner I don't know why but only an exception message will display

Comment: you can read through this to get started on validators for both client and server in asp.net https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972961.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refresh the page while exception occurs just put this

```
catch
{
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
}
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a try catch block and place your response in catch and your throw in

```
    if (SerNo.Reason == null)
    {
        try{
            throw new Exception("Must select reason");
        } 
        catch{
            Response.Redirect("Job.aspx?JobID=" + Request.QueryString["JobID"], false); 
        }

    }
```

or you could replace `throw new Exception("Must select reason");` for `MessageBox.Show("Must select reason")` then leave the method from there.